# Ajax issues with the "Add section" button

Tags: 8, ajax, layout-builder

We're trying to use the new Layout Builder to configure some of our content types. When we click the "Add section" button under Manage Layout, we get the following errors:

On the page in the console

```
An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 200
Debugging information follows.
Path: /layout_builder/choose/section/defaults/node.page.default/0
StatusText: OK
ResponseText:
```

In the dblog:

> Error: Class 'Drupal\Core\Layout\Icon\SvgIconBuilder' not found in
> Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService() (line
> 265 of
> /srv/bindings/457ee32ddc46445586081eaf84bc7c25/code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php)
> #0 /srv/bindings/457ee32ddc46445586081eaf84bc7c25/code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(173):
> Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService(Array,
> 'layout.icon_bui...') #1
> /srv/bindings/457ee32ddc46445586081eaf84bc7c25/code/web/core/lib/Drupal.php(158):
> Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('layout.icon_bui...')
> #2 /srv/bindings/457ee32ddc46445586081eaf84bc7c25/code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Layout/LayoutDefinition.php(459):
> Drupal::service('layout.icon_bui...') #3
> /srv/bindings/457ee32ddc46445586081eaf84bc7c25/code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Layout/LayoutDefinition.php(436):
> Drupal\Core\Layout\LayoutDefinition->getIconBuilder() #4
> /srv/bindings/457ee32ddc46445586081eaf84bc7c25/code/web/core/modules/layout_builder/src/Controller/ChooseSectionController.php(72):
> Drupal\Core\Layout\LayoutDefinition->getIcon(60, 80, 1, 3) #5
> [internal function]:
> Drupal\layout_builder\Controller\ChooseSectionController->build(Object(Drupal\layout_builder\Plugin\SectionStorage\DefaultsSectionStorage),
> '1') #6
> /srv/bindings/457ee32ddc46445586081eaf84bc7c25/code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(123):
> call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #7
> /srv/bindings/457ee32ddc46445586081eaf84bc7c25/code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(582):
> Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}()
> #8 /srv/bindings/457ee32ddc46445586081eaf84bc7c25/code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(124):
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object(Drupal\Core\Render\RenderContext),
> Object(Closure)) #9
> /srv/bindings/457ee32ddc46445586081eaf84bc7c25/code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(97):
> Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array,
> Array) #10
> /srv/bindings/457ee32ddc46445586081eaf84bc7c25/code/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(151):
> Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}()
> #11 /srv/bindings/457ee32ddc46445586081eaf84bc7c25/code/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(68):
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request),
>
> 1. #12
>    /srv/bindings/457ee32ddc46445586081eaf84bc7c25/code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/Session.php(57):
>    Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request),
>    1, true) #13
>    /srv/bindings/457ee32ddc46445586081eaf84bc7c25/code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/KernelPreHandle.php(47):
>    Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request),
>    1, true) #14
>    /srv/bindings/457ee32ddc46445586081eaf84bc7c25/code/web/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(106):
>    Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request),
>    1, true) #15
>    /srv/bindings/457ee32ddc46445586081eaf84bc7c25/code/web/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(85):
>    Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request),
>    1, true) #16
>    /srv/bindings/457ee32ddc46445586081eaf84bc7c25/code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/ReverseProxyMiddleware.php(47):
>    Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request),
>    1, true) #17
>    /srv/bindings/457ee32ddc46445586081eaf84bc7c25/code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/NegotiationMiddleware.php(52):
>    Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request),
>    1, true) #18
>    /srv/bindings/457ee32ddc46445586081eaf84bc7c25/code/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php(23):
>    Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request),
>    1, true) #19
>    /srv/bindings/457ee32ddc46445586081eaf84bc7c25/code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php(693):
>    Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request),
>    1, true) #20
>    /srv/bindings/457ee32ddc46445586081eaf84bc7c25/code/web/index.php(19):
>    Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
>    #21 {main}.

I would appreciate any knowledge on this!! If it makes any difference, we're hosting this on a multidev on Pantheon

Comment: Do you have `Icon` in your `.gitignore`?

Comment: @Clive yes I do, what should I do about that?

Comment: Removing that line should be fine, afterwards commit any missing files and try again